# Puppeteer-pdf Heroku says :invalid_exec_path

Tags: heroku, puppeteer, heroku-toolbelt, elixir

I have a an elixir application that use [Puppeteer-pdf](https://github.com/coletiv/puppeteer-pdf). It works fine on local machine and generates the pdf from html. On Heroku it throws the error {:error, :invalid_exec_path}. I have added the [puppeteer build pack](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack) on heroku, What is it that i am doing wrong. Thanks for taking time to answer this.

Comment: Can you add some more description like stacktrace and what have you tried etc?

Comment: The PuppeteerPdf.Generate.from_string returns this error. I have only added heroku buildpack for puppeteer.

Comment: I rather installed puppeteer-pdf locally and set the execution path as 
config :puppeteer_pdf, exec_path: File.cwd!() <> "/assets/node_modules/.bin/puppeteer-pdf"
in configs. The buildpack was added already.